# How to Parse XML String c#

Tags: c#, xml, webrequest

I'm trying to parse XML string into list, result count is always zero.

```
 string result = "";
            string address = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";

            // Create the web request  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                // Read the whole contents and return as a string  
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

            var ListCurr = doc.Descendants("Cube").Select(curr => new CurrencyType() 
                    { Name = curr.Element("currency").Value, Value = float.Parse(curr.Element("rate").Value) }).ToList();
```

where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @BassamAlugili: It's really not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Manish I have remove it and vote to you! When Jon answer a question then that must be a good question! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're looking for elements without a namespace, whereas the XML contains this in the root element:

```
xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"
```

That specifies the *default* namespace for any element. Also, `currency` and `rate` are *attributes* within the `Cube` elements - they're not subelements.

So you want something like:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";
var currencies = doc.Descendants(ns + "Cube")
                    .Select(c => new CurrencyType {
                                     Name = (string) c.Attribute("currency"),
                                     Value = (decimal) c.Attribute("rate")
                                 })
                    .ToList();
```

Note that because I'm casting the `currency` attribute to `string`, you'll end up with a null `Name` property for any currencies which don't specify that attribute. If you want to skip those elements, you can do so with a `Where` clause either before or after the `Select`.

Also note that I've changed the type of `Value` to `decimal` rather than `float` - you shouldn't use `float` for currency-related values. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c) for more details.)

Additionally, you should consider using [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx) to load the XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(address);
```

Then there's no need to create the `WebRequest` etc yourself.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(address);

Comment: @Manish: I've now edited it to use `decimal` rather than `float` - and please see my comment on the answer that you've accepted, as that won't work as-is if the current thread culture uses `,` as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";

var ListCurr = doc.Descendants(ns + "Cube")
                    .Where(c=>c.Attribute("currency")!=null) //<-- Some "Cube"s do not have currency attr.
                    .Select(curr => new CurrencyType  
                    { 
                        Name = curr.Attribute("currency").Value, 
                        Value = float.Parse(curr.Attribute("rate").Value) 
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: It would be good to actually *explain* what the problem was rather than just posting the code. I'd also recommend using the cast rather than `float.Parse` - this code will fail in cultures which use comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, but you've already explained it very well.